# Simple way of creating dummy variable in R by using cut command

Tags: r

I have a data for linear regression model, i want to cut by three to regress dummy variable, length of my data is 51 observations. i want to cut it by: from beginning until 21st observation and 21st to 38th and 38th to 51st. how can i do this using cut command in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say

```
brkvec <- c(21,38,51)
dummyfac <- cut(1:51,breaks=c(0,brkvec))
```

test:

```
table(dummyfac)
## (0,21] (21,38] (38,51] 
##     21      17      13
```

Alternatively

```
dummyfac <- factor(rep(1:3,c(21,diff(brkvec)))
```

It's not entirely clear what you mean by "until 21st observation": is the 21st observation supposed to be in the first level or the second level of the factor? If the latter, try using `right=FALSE` in `cut(...)`

Comment: i mean from first observation to 21st observation is in 1st group, second is[22:38] and third is [38:51]